# Can the stabiliser of a 'parabolic end' of a group stabilise an invariant line?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting freely and cocompactly on an infinite-ended graph $\Gamma$. In particular, $G$ is finitely generated and acts as a convergence group on the Cantor set $\rm Ends(\Gamma)$.

Let $\omega \in \rm Ends(\Gamma)$ be a 'parabolic point' for this action. That is, every non-torsion element of $G$ which fixes $\omega$ does not fix any other point, and this stabiliser contains some non-torsion element. The question is then the following.

> Is it possible that there exists some simple bi-infinite line $L \subset \Gamma$ such that ${\rm Stab}(L) = 
>  {\rm Stab}(\omega)$?

If such a line existed, then we'd have that the stabiliser of the parabolic point $\omega$ is two-ended.
If we then assume that $G$ is accessible, in the sense of Wall/Dunwoody, one can pass to a maximal finite splitting and provide obtain a contradiction quite quickly, since here a parabolic end must secretly be the end of some one-ended vertex group.

I'm wondering if there is something more general happening here. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with some findings, as I now suspect this question is hard.

There is work of B. Krön in this direction, in the specific case of planar graphs [1]. In this work, the author shows that a planar (say, 3-connected) almost-transitive planar graph cannot contain a 'bi-infinite facial-ray' with both ends of this ray lying in the same end of the graph.

If we restrict ourselves to 3-connected graphs, then such a bi-infinite face path with one end would satisfy my requirements. This observation follows from Whitney's uniqueness theorem for emebeddings of 3-connected planar graphs. In order to rule these bad faces out, Krön uses the theorem that almost transitive graphs are accessible.

That an almost-transitive planar graph cannot have these 'bad faces' was first conjectured by Bonnington, Richter, and Watkins [2]. Since this specific case of planar graphs was interesting in its own right, one is left to suspect that the general problem laid out above is probably quite difficult, though I'd love to be proven wrong.

---

[1] Krön, B. (2006). Infinite faces and ends of almost transitive plane graphs. Preprint.

[2] C.P. Bonnington, R.B. Richter, M.E. Watkins, Between Ends and Fibers, preprint (2005)